# Does using non-native resolutions with the same aspect ratio as the native resolution cause loss of quality?

Tags: resolution

I have a 22 inch Full HD IPS monitor with native resolution of 1920 * 1080 but it's too small for me, and the Windows DPI doesn't work properly corss-software, so I use the custom resolution of 1376 * 774 with the same aspect ratio as native resolution namely 16:9, does it make a big impact on the quality that I'm getting with this monitor?

Comment: Look at the image, the image quality is subjective...

Comment: Well, if full HD on a 22" is too small but your resolution is legible and usable then it seems the image quality is better from a subjective standpoint...

Comment: I've assumed that monitor pixels are physical and as long as I keep the aspect ratio and the image doesn't get distorted it's OK, is it true? I mean not just from my point of view but is it true enough to recommend it to someone else?

Comment: Mapping a different resolution to your screen may not be the best way to improve its usability.  The best solution depends on what you are looking at.  If you are editing images, nothing will be a replacement for the actual pixels.  If the problem is reading text, you can change the system font.  For general usability, you can select to use large icons and large text.  Within your applications software, you can set the default zoom level higher.  Bigger isn't always better, though.  Smaller and sharper can be better than bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quality depends on the monitor. You *may* think you're getting a resolution of 1376 * 774, but that's physically impossible. So the monitor will approximate the result, by taking mapping pixels in the input signal to pixels on the screen.

The simplest method is to just copy the closest pixel value. Of course, since there are more pixels on the screen than in the input, it means some pixels are copied more than once (up to 4 times), but others are copied only once. Smarter monitors contain logic to estimate pixel values using smarter mathematical algorithms.

I wouldn't count on the latter, though. As videocards became more capable, the need for such logic decreased and manufacturers have been cutting costs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. Some monitors have a scaler, which handles the conversion internally - I have a screen that's 1280x800 native but handles anything down to 640x480 and up to full HD with an internal scaler without looking horrible. However, I generally don't see this listed, and rule of thumb still tends to be to output at native resolution.

I'd try it, then decide for myself. Image quality is pretty subjective